# <Reason.h> header file can't be found (no such file or directory)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, header, shutdown

I'm trying to write a program to reboot a machine at a certain time using the following C code:

```
//A program to reboot the computer

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winbase.h>
#include <Winuser.h>
#include <Reason.h>


void myExitWindowsEx (UINT uFlags, DWORD dwReason) {

HANDLE handleToTokenUID;
LUID   UUIDShutDownPermission;
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES PrivProperties;

OpenProcessToken (GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY,  &handleToTokenUID);

LookupPrivilegeValue (NULL, "SeShutdownPrivilege", &UUIDShutDownPermission);

PrivProperties.PrivilegeCount = 1;
PrivProperties.Privileges[0].Luid = UUIDShutDownPermission;
PrivProperties.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

AdjustTokenPrivileges (handleToTokenUID, FALSE, &PrivProperties, 0, NULL, NULL);

ExitWindowsEx(uFlags, dwReason);
}


int main (void) {

struct _SYSTEMTIME time;

void myExitWindowsEx (UINT uFlags, DWORD dwReason);

//Now we are calling the function to reboot the computer with appropriate flags

while (1) {
Sleep (59000);
GetSystemTime;
if (time.wHour == 3 && time.wMinute == 0) {
myExitWindowsEx(EWX_REBOOT, SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED);
break; }
}

return 0;
}
```

but getting an error that `SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED` (Windows shutdown reason which is a required parameter to `ExitWindowsEx`) is not defined. The reason is that `Reason.h` header file can't be found by the compiler.

Google search didn't return any relevant results, MSDN doesn't seem to cover that as well.

Did anyone have to work with  header or receive a similar error? I thought it might have any dependencies on other header files, but couldn't find any info on that as well.

Comment: MS Software Development Kit installed. That should contain all of MS header files, but <Reason.h> is not available. IDE: Bloodshed Dev-C++

Comment: Reason.h not found? There's a pun in here somewhere... Anyway Bloodshed is awesome but very old (i learned how to program on that thing) and I'm pretty sure it's unmaintained. Switch to Eclipse, CodeBlocks, Visual Studio or anywhere else

Comment: Thanks! Gonna try Visual Studio later tonight.

Comment: Pelles-C is also a C compiler that comes with the headers. I just checked and it has reason.h included.

Comment: @rath Thanks for the hint. Compiled successfully in Visual Studio.

Comment: Here you can find the values: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376885(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I saw that. That's where the <Reason.h> header came from. These codes will not be recognized if that is omitted. Anyway, the issue was with the particular IDE I was using.